# How does the controller to capture data from a form developed in jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, model-view-controller, spring

[spring 3.0.5]

My user object:

```
public class UserForm {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    @Email
    private String email;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

UserAddress object

```
 public class AddressForm {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    private String addressName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    private String street;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    private String city;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 19)
    private String country;

    public String getAddressName() {
        return addressName;
    }

    public void setAddressName(String addressName) {
        this.addressName = addressName;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

My JSP page

```
<form:form id="registerForm" commandName="userForm" action="registered">
<form:input id="firstName" path="firstName" /><form:errors path="firstName" />
<form:input id="lastName" path="lastName" /><form:errors path="lastName" />
<form:input id="email" path="email" /><form:errors path="email" />
<input type="button" value="add address" />
<input type="button" value="del address" />
<input type="button" value="SUBMIT" />
</form:form>
```

I want to see after pressing the button Add URL (remove the address), there are fields for the object AddressForm. Adding fields using jquery did something like this:

```
var i  = 0:
$("#addbtn").click(function() {
    $("#someId").append(
         '<input type="text" name="street_' + i + '" />' + 
         '<input type="text" name="city_'   + i + '" />');
    i++;
});
```

My Controller have mapping method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registered", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String varify(@ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm, HttpServletRequest req) {
        return "redirect:index";
}
```

How does the controller to capture data from a form developed in jquery?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind values into array/list to your bean. For this case if list is dynamic you might need to use LazyList (apache common collection) in your form object.

```
private List<String> city = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(),
          FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(String.class));
// getter /setter
```

And in your jquery :

```
var i  = 0:
$("#addbtn").click(function() {
    $("#someId").append(
         '<input type="text" name="street[' + i + ']" />' + 
         '<input type="text" name="city['   + i + ']" />');
    i++;
});
```